# Pycharm error while running Pyspark code on windows

Tags: windows, pyspark, pycharm

WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/05/21 12:55:53 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning you can still run the pyspark code. From pycharm you have to use spark-submit to execute your code. Use pyspark when you want to use REPL.